# Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder, how to add row elements of specific columns

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder

I am working in SSRB and I need to the row elements of 3 different columns in 1 column. Note that the report has more than 3 columns and I cannot just use a universal sum command, it has to be these row elements in these 3 columns. In Excel,this is easy, just sum the values and drag the formula along to down the summing column. In SQL this is achieved by a query command 
SELECT SUM(aggregate_expression)
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
but I am not sure how to go about this in SSRB. Anybody have experience with this?

Comment: Can you add any kind of visual representation of your desired result?    I cannot picture what you are trying to do.

Comment: Basically, if I have cell A1, B1, C1 in excel and I want to add them up in D1, I would just use SUM(A1...), correct? I am attempt to do that same thing but in SSRB, where that 4th cell automatically holds the sum of the 3 preceding it. I am trying to build this into the report.

Answer (score 0):

If you have respective query then do one thing. Create sql query and use that as source in your report builder query section.
It will show you result as shown in query.

For your help please check below attached screenshot about query section :
[image: Report Builder Query]

You can change query and click on 'OK' Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your "D1" box an expression using the other 3 boxes ids, like this:

```
reportitems!Textbox581.Value  + reportitems!Textbox582.Value +reportitems!Textbox583.Value
```

Comment: ok, I tried that and the result was an error "The Value expression for the text box‘TextBoxName’ refers to the report item ‘NameOfTexboxInTablix’.
     Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope. 
      Letters in the names of report items must use the correct case." Do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: No, it's one of the two reasons given in the error message, but without seeing your project, I can't tell which one.

Comment: What are the reasons, if you would be so kind as to tell me, I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: They are stated in the error:   1)  "Report item expressions can only refer to other report items within the same grouping scope or a containing grouping scope".   or 2)  "Letters in the names of report items must use the correct case".   You might start by googling the error message.

Comment: When you say box IDs, are you referring to the cells in the report or the values in the data set? I know you can input parameters and use an expression, but can you do the same for cells when the report runs?  For example, I know you can use an expression to find T3=T2-T1 and have the user define T1,T2, but if I am pulling data into the report from a server, can I define T3=T2-T1 if T2 and T1 are feilds/report items?

Comment: In my example, `Textbox581` is the ID of a cell in the report.   If you want to do this with Fields in a dataset, you can, but the `T3` cell you are populating must be in the same Tablix as the Fields `T1` & `T2`.   If you want to populate a cell in another area of the report, you can only do it by using Cell ID's.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Do the cells containing T1 and T2 need to be static values or can they be generated when the report is run? Can I input a formula to a row in a column, point it at the columns that can contain T1, T2 and instruct SSRS to evaluate the expression row by row? I know thats likely what you are doing in your example but I am getting errors when I try the following:  =Fields!ValueFloat2.Value-Fields!ValueFloat1.Value.